# range of a function defined by expectation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, improper-integrals

Given $c>0$ and define a function $f:(0,\infty)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{equation}
f(\sigma)=\frac1{\sqrt {2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\max\{-c,\min\{x,c\}\}^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}.
\end{equation}
We can see $f$ as the second moment of $X_c=\max\{-c,\min\{X,c\}\}$ where $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. I'd like to find the range of $f$. I have proved that $f$ is strictly increasing but I still don't know it limits when $\sigma\to 0,\infty$. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

PS: we also be able to express $f$ by
\begin{equation}
f(\sigma)=2c^2(1-\phi(c))+\sigma^2(2\phi(c)-1)
\end{equation}
where $\phi(c)=P(X\leq c$).

Comment: But if you say you can write $f$ as $f(\sigma)=2c^2(1-\phi (c))+\sigma^2 (2\phi(c)-1)$ then $f$ is a concave quadratic function if $\phi(c)<1/2$ and convex if $\phi(c)>1/2$ and in both cases it is easy to find the range: If $\phi(c)<1/2$ then it is $[f(min),\infty)$ where $min$ means the value where $f$ has a minimum and respectively for $\phi(c)>1/2$.

Comment: @Martingalo: First thanks for your help. But, $\phi(c)$ still involves $\sigma$

Comment: Aha! of course it does :) $\phi_{\sigma^2}(c) = \phi(c/\sigma)$ where $\phi$ is the density of $N(0,1)$ now. Ok, let's think :)

Comment: I meant $\phi_{\sigma^2}(c) = \frac{1}{\sigma}\phi(c/\sigma)$ :)

Comment: Yes, you missed $\sigma$. By the way, I think it is easy to see that $f\to \infty$ as $\sigma\to\infty$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you and even at $-\infty$ too. Moreover, I think it is not so hard to differentiate $f$ w.r.t. $\sigma$ (boring but doable) and equal 0, I did it very quick and I got some term that cannot be zero times $\sigma^2 +\sigma - c^2=0$ (don't trust this but in any case I guess you will get a 2nd degree eq.) then this together With the limits should give you the range.

Comment: At present the function to be integrated is odd hence $f(\sigma)=0$ for every $\sigma$. But since you mention the "second moment", a square might be missing somewhere on the RHS of the identity defining $f(\sigma)$. Please explain.

Comment: @Did: Thanks for your correction. I've edited my formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that $f$ is actually
$$
f(\sigma)=\frac1{\sqrt {2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\max\{-c,\min\{x,c\}\}^{\color{red}{\bf 2}}\mathrm e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}\mathrm dx.
$$
Define $u_c:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ by $u(t)=\min\{t,c^2\}$ and consider a standard normal random variable $Z$. Then,
$$
f(\sigma)=E(u_c(\sigma^2Z^2)).
$$
Since $u_c$ is nondecreasing, $f$ is nondecreasing (and actually increasing). Since $u_c$ is continuous and bounded with $u_c(0)=0$ and $u_c(\infty)=c^2$, one has $\lim\limits_{\sigma\to0}f(\sigma)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{\sigma\to\infty}f(\sigma)=c^2$.

For the limit when $\sigma\to\infty$, note that $\sigma^2Z^2\to\infty$ almost surely hence $u_c(\sigma^2Z^2)\to c^2$ almost surely and the domination $u_c(\sigma^2Z^2)\leqslant c^2$ allows to conclude.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, this is in the post.

Comment: By the way @Did, can you see $f$ is increasing without derivative? Thanks

Comment: By the way, the approach I explained yields this readily: the function $u_c$ is nondecreasing hence, if $\sigma\lt\tau$ then $u_c(\sigma^2Z^2)\leqslant u_c(\tau^2Z^2)$ almost surely.